Socket.IO: No acknowledgment received from client after server emits event
I am using Socket.IO to emit an event from the server to a specific client. The event is being successfully received on the client side, and the client processes the data without any errors. However, the server does not receive the acknowledgment callback even though the client explicitly calls it
Server-side code
async function emitData(
    socket: Socket,
    targetSocketId: string,
    event: configUpdate,
    data: any,
    callback: Function,
    mpu_id: string
) {
    console.log('Emitting event:', event, 'to socket ID:', targetSocketId);
    try {
        socket.to(targetSocketId).emit(event, data, async (acknowledgment: any) => {
        console.log('Acknowledgment received:', acknowledgment); 
            if (acknowledgment && acknowledgment.status === 'ok') {
                await updateSendToMpu(mpu_id);
                callback({ status: 'ok', message: `${event} successfully updated.` });
            } else {
                callback({
                   status: 'error',
                    message: acknowledgment
                        ? 'Client failed to acknowledge.'
                        : 'No acknowledgment received from client.',
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error emitting data:', error);
        callback({ status: 'error', message: 'Failed to emit event.' });
    }
}

Client-side code
socket.on('configUpdate', async (data, callback = () => {}) => {
  console.log('Callback type:', typeof callback);
  try {
     if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
       console.error('Callback is not a function');
       return;
    }
    console.log('Received configuration update from server:', data);
    const entries = Object.entries(data);
    if (entries.length === 0) {
      console.warn('No configuration data provided.');
      callback({ status: 'ok', message: 'No configuration data to process.' });
      return;
    }
 
  callback({ status: 'ok', message: 'Configuration processed successfully.' });
    console.log('Configuration processed successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error processing configuration update:', error);
    callback({ status: 'error', message: `Error processing data: ${error.message}` });
  }
});
```   from client side **console.log('Configuration processed successfully.');** is printing correctly on server side its shows **console.log('Acknowledgment received:', acknowledgment);**  
Could someone guide me on what might be causing this issue or suggest debugging steps? Any help is appreciated, as I’m new to Socket.IO.





The event name configUpdate matches between the server and client.
The client logs show the data is received and processed correctly.
I’ve confirmed the callback type is a function on the client side.


worked when i used client.socket.emit(event, data, async (acknowledgment: any) insted of socket.to(targetSocketId).emit

It should be due to below reasons

Socket.IO Version Compatibility:- Please Confirm that both the server and client are using compatible versions of Socket.IO and Make sure both are aligned For example:
Run npm list socket.io on the server.
Run npm list socket.io-client on the client.
Network or Middleware Issues


thanks for replying Vaibhav i tried by checking the npm list └── socket.io-client@4.8.1 └── socket.io@4.8.1 both seems working at same version. still the problem is not resolved ack shows null on server side.
